# How to switch the control from one browser to another browser for automating the application in VBScript?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, browser-automation

I am automating a web application which is opening a another model Pop up browser. But the control remains in the first browser itself. I want to switch the control to the recently opened popup browser. Please provide me the solution that how it could be done by using Vb Script?

Comment: I don't know the best way with VB exactly.  But JS offers a "focus()" which allows you to set the focus to whatever happens to be going on.

Answer (score 0):

In vbscript you can simply put

```
response.write("<script>window.showModalDialog('showWindow.asp?param=1&paramba=2&etc...',labelToClick.labelValue);</script>")
```

Just need to make sure that it will be readed while page loads.
Or you can use JS openModal window like this

```
function openModalWindowWithAllText(){
window.showModalDialog("showWindow.asp?param=1&paramba=2&etc...",labelToClick.labelValue);
}
```

and call it on body onload.

Problem would be that some of the browser manufacturers already declared  showModalDialog  depreciated.

On other hand you can use showModelessDialog which is not a depreciated and main difference that you can move focus back-forth between it and parent window while it stays on top of the parent window until popup is closed.

Best way for you, if you going to use modal window, would be to use AJAX and in third option is a simple JS function setFocus
like this:

```
function SetFocus(fieldId)
{
document.getElementById(fieldId).focus();
}
```

and call this function on "body onload='SetFocus(Fieldsid);'" event for your new page.As far as I know all browsers supports that. Fieldsid could be anything on your new page or it could be just hard coded id of existing element where focus could be pointed to, like text field, dropdown etc.

However if user on the local machine(or network) have policy to block popup your only option is a modal windows.